# Parallel HTTPRequest using HttpClient in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient for sending HTTP requests and receiving HTTP responses in my Windows 8 app. I have few questions on the same:

1) Can I send multiple/parallel HTTP requests using a single HttpClient object? Is there a recommended way to use HttpClient object efficiently?

2) What is the difference when I create HttpClient object every time and when I re-use the same object for each new request?

3) I am tracking the requests and responses using Fiddler. What I found out is that the response time in Fiddler is different than the response time I am calculating manually inside my App. The response time for a request in Fiddler is always lower than the calculated response time in my app. Can anybody please tell me why it is like that?

4) One more thing I came across is that for every request it is doing HTTPS handshake. Instead it should do it only first time. I checked it using Fiddler and it is clearly visible there. Is there any property I need to set in HttpClient object to stop this from doing it every time.

5) Whether HttpClient is thread-safe?

Answer (score 3):

1 & 5:

> [HttpClient manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx):
>
> The following methods are thread safe:
>
> 1. CancelPendingRequests
> 2. DeleteAsync
> 3. GetAsync
> 4. GetByteArrayAsync
> 5. GetStreamAsync
> 6. GetStringAsync
> 7. PostAsync
> 8. PutAsync
> 9. SendAsync

2 & 4:

> [HttpClient manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx):
>
> The HttpClient class instance acts as a session to send HTTP requests.

3:

Fiddler acts as a proxy. Your browser sends the request to Fiddler, which forwards it to the origin server. This adds upon the request time.

Comment: Regarding 1), they're thread-safe, but it is not permitted to perform multiple requests at the same time.  However, when you use the *Async() variants, you can simply call `ContinueWith()` on the returned `Task` to chain multiple requests.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use the same HttpClient object for each async HttpRequest which will prevent it from overlapping the requests